# Difference (upon custom attributes) between two arrays having partial similar objects i.e a-b

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, arraylist, difference

How to find difference between two JavaScript arrays having partial similar objects?

Diff = A minus B

```
const firstList = [{ key: "aa", name:"a" }, { key: "bb", name:"b" }, { key: "cc", name:"c" }];
const secondList = [{ key: "dd", id: 1 }, { key: "cc", id: 2 }];
```

I want something like `const diff = firstList - secondList;`

In this case `diff` needs to hold `[ { key: 'aa', name: 'a' }, { key: 'bb', name: 'b' } ]`

Comment: You could use lodash's without https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const firstList = [{ key: "aa", name:"a" }, { key: "bb", name:"b" }, { key: "cc", name:"c" }];
const secondList = [{ key: "dd", id: 1 }, { key: "cc", id: 2 }];

const diff = firstList.filter((first) => {
  return !secondList.some((second) => second.key === first.key);
});

diff; // [ { key: 'aa', name: 'a' }, { key: 'bb', name: 'b' } ]
```

Comment: This works. But consider replacing the inner `.filter` with `.some`, which feels more natural than using a `filter` and comparing length to 0. Eg: `return !secondList.some(second => second.key === first.key)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Set` for the second array and filter the first array for excluding elements with same `key` of the second array.

```js
const
    firstList = [{ key: "aa" }, { key: "bb" }, { key: "cc" }],
    secondList = [{ key: "dd" }, { key: "cc" }],
    keys = new Set(secondList.map(({ key }) => key)),
    result = firstList.filter(({ key }) => !keys.has(key));

console.log(result);
```